# ADO.Net Entity Model - Is there a dialog for selecting the database?

Tags: c#, connection-string, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am looking for the standard dialog that will allow a user to create a database, connect to an existing database, select the database, test connection, etc.. and create the connection string from that. Is there some standard control for this?